# keras: Can the test data be used for early_stoppage and model checkpoint

Tags: python, keras

I have same question here, I have only two data sets, one for test and train. I am using test data as the validation_data for the **keras model.fit** function like this.

```
      model.fit(X_train,y_train,
      batch_size=64,
      epochs=epochs,
      callbacks=[es,reduceLROnPlateau,modelCheckpoint],
      validation_data=(X_test,y_test),
      verbose=2)
```

I am using **Early** stop, **ReduceLROnPlateau** and **ModelCheckpoint**. All on the `val_loss`. My objective is to get the training to stop where the test accuracy or auc score is highest. Since the validation data is not contributing to the training, is this alright to do it this way? Futher details, my test_data contains completely different/unseen objects than train data, so even when I make validation data from splitting the train data it is not a great indicator for the generalization performance of my network on test data. So the results I am getting are they scientifically fair or its **cheating**? What's the best practice in this?

```
Train on 39840 samples, validate on 7440 samples
Epoch 1/30
 - 257s - loss: 0.6046 - acc: 0.7782 - val_loss: 0.6797 - val_acc: 0.8055

Epoch 00001: val_loss improved from inf to 0.67972, saving model to keras_densenet_simple_wt_28Sept.h5
Epoch 2/30
 - 253s - loss: 0.5055 - acc: 0.8236 - val_loss: 0.5370 - val_acc: 0.8085

Epoch 00002: val_loss improved from 0.67972 to 0.53701, saving model to keras_densenet_simple_wt_28Sept.h5
Epoch 3/30
 - 253s - loss: 0.4506 - acc: 0.8518 - val_loss: 0.6623 - val_acc: 0.7937

Epoch 00003: val_loss did not improve from 0.53701
Epoch 4/30
 - 253s - loss: 0.4110 - acc: 0.8711 - val_loss: 0.6583 - val_acc: 0.7995

Epoch 00004: val_loss did not improve from 0.53701
Epoch 5/30
 - 253s - loss: 0.3726 - acc: 0.8908 - val_loss: 0.5282 - val_acc: 0.8237

Epoch 00005: val_loss improved from 0.53701 to 0.52820, saving model to keras_densenet_simple_wt_28Sept.h5
Epoch 6/30
 - 253s - loss: 0.3427 - acc: 0.9035 - val_loss: 0.4683 - val_acc: 0.8422

Epoch 00006: val_loss improved from 0.52820 to 0.46830, saving model to keras_densenet_simple_wt_28Sept.h5
Epoch 7/30
 - 253s - loss: 0.3148 - acc: 0.9152 - val_loss: 0.5580 - val_acc: 0.8109

Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve from 0.46830
Epoch 8/30
 - 253s - loss: 0.2928 - acc: 0.9241 - val_loss: 0.5347 - val_acc: 0.8290

Epoch 00008: val_loss did not improve from 0.46830
Epoch 9/30
 - 252s - loss: 0.2719 - acc: 0.9334 - val_loss: 0.7429 - val_acc: 0.7800

Epoch 00009: val_loss did not improve from 0.46830
Epoch 10/30
 - 252s - loss: 0.2563 - acc: 0.9389 - val_loss: 0.8768 - val_acc: 0.7226

Epoch 00010: val_loss did not improve from 0.46830
Epoch 11/30
 - 252s - loss: 0.2413 - acc: 0.9449 - val_loss: 0.9852 - val_acc: 0.7405

Epoch 00011: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 9.486833431105525e-05.

Epoch 00011: val_loss did not improve from 0.46830
Epoch 00011: early stopping
7440/7440 [==============================] - 15s 2ms/step
Present Test accuracy: 0.740
Present auc_score ------------------>  0.896
7440/7440 [==============================] - 17s 2ms/step
Loading Best saved model by model checkpoint
Best saved model Test accuracy: 0.842
best saved model Auc_score ------------------>  0.922
```

======================================================================

Comment: Strictly speaking, model selection using test data is not ideal, since by doing so your model is biased towards the test set.  One thing you can do (I suppose) would be to split the test set into two, one for validation, the other merely for evaluation.

Comment: This is a new idea I did not think about. Thanks. I will try to split test data. Though its kinda less numbers already. :)

Comment: Probably this book covers the topic more in depth (not 100% sure though).  http://www.mlyearning.org/